# Do I need an index on N+1 columns, to efficiently do a SELECT on the N columns, and sort by the other?

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

Suppose I have a table like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    column_A [...],
    column_B [...],
    column_C [...],
    column_X INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0, -- type not really relevant
    INDEX a_b_c (column_A, column_B, column_C),
    INDEX x (column_X)
);
```

so basically it has an index on columns A,B,C and an index con column X.

Now suppose I want to do perform a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column_A = <something> AND column_B = <something> AND column_C = <SOMETHING>
ORDER BY column_X
```

Are the indexes above enough to make this as efficient as it can get, or would it benefit from having also an index on all the four columns?

Comment: You're using SELECT * to select all the fields from mytable, but will you actually be using all the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the 3 tests use `=`, then this would avoid doing a sort:

```
INDEX(A,B,C,X)
```

(And toss `INDEX(A,B,C)` as being redundant.)

MySQL essentially never uses two different indexes in a single `SELECT`.  Anyway the `INDEX(x)` is useless in this context.

One way to discover some of what I say:

1. Run `EXPLAIN SELECT` on  what you have.
2. Add my 4-col index and rerun `EXPLAIN`.
3. DROP the 3-col index and rerun `EXPLAIN`.

- "Key_len" indicates how many columns of the index are used for the `WHERE`.
- "Using filesort" indicates that the index was *not* used for `ORDER BY`.  (The name is misleading -- the sorting may *or may not* actually use a disk file; it could be done in RAM.)

More on indexing:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)